# Azure Text to speech is not using the lexicon I created

Tags: azure-speech

I use the text to speech from Azure and created a lexicon via the the buttons.
Unfortunatally the content of the lexicon does not get uesed by azure.
Neither the alias nor phonemes, even the examples (BTW - By the Way) are not used.

I tried to connect several lexicons, but it never worked.

Comment: Can you please share the lexicon file and error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug in Audio content creation Tool, created backlog for the same.